# Pandas DataFrame column to list

Tags: python, pandas

I am pulling a subset of data from a column based on conditions in another column being met.

I can get the correct values back but it is in pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.  How do I convert that to list?

```
import pandas as pd

tst = pd.read_csv('C:\\SomeCSV.csv')

lookupValue = tst['SomeCol'] == "SomeValue"
ID = tst[lookupValue][['SomeCol']]
#How To convert ID to a list
```

Comment: I am hesitant to edit a question this old and with so many views, but it should be pointed out that although the title talks about a "dataframe to list", the question is about a "series to list".  And note that while `tst` is a dataframe, `tst['SomeCol']` is a series.  The distinction matters in that the `tolist()` method works directly on a series, but not on a dataframe.

Comment: Note that it may actually be more convenient to use the DataFrame than lists.

Comment: If you came here looking to find out how to convert a DATAFRAME to a list (of lists), check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists/28006809

Answer (score 338):

You can use the [`Series.to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) method.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9],
                   'b': [3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9]})

print(df['a'].to_list())
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

To drop duplicates you can do one of the following:

```
>>> df['a'].drop_duplicates().to_list()
[1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 9]
>>> list(set(df['a'])) # as pointed out by EdChum
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks that works!  I want to delete the duplicates out of the ID list.  I tried using set(ID) but gives an error saying TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: you can just do `list(set(df['a'])`

Comment: @MartienLubberink why is it better? wouldnt a set data structure use up more space?

Answer (score 30):

I'd like to clarify a few things:

1. As other answers have pointed out, the simplest thing to do is use
   `pandas.Series.tolist()`.  I'm not sure why the top voted answer
   leads off with using `pandas.Series.values.tolist()` since as far as I can tell, it adds syntax/confusion with no added benefit.
2. `tst[lookupValue][['SomeCol']]` is a dataframe (as stated in the
   question), not a series (as stated in a comment to the question).  This is because `tst[lookupValue]` is a dataframe, and slicing it with `[['SomeCol']]` asks for
   a list of columns (that list that happens to have a length of 1), resulting in a dataframe being returned.  If you
   remove the extra set of brackets, as in
   `tst[lookupValue]['SomeCol']`, then you are asking for just that one
   column rather than a list of columns, and thus you get a series back.
3. You need a series to use `pandas.Series.tolist()`, so you should
   definitely skip the second set of brackets in this case.  FYI, if you
   ever end up with a one-column dataframe that isn't easily avoidable
   like this, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.squeeze()` to convert it to
   a series.
4. `tst[lookupValue]['SomeCol']` is getting a subset of a particular column via
   chained slicing.  It slices once to get a dataframe with only certain rows
   left, and then it slices again to get a certain column.  You can get
   away with it here since you are just reading, not writing, but
   the proper way to do it is `tst.loc[lookupValue, 'SomeCol']` (which returns a series).
5. Using the syntax from #4, you could reasonably do everything in one line: `ID = tst.loc[tst['SomeCol'] == 'SomeValue', 'SomeCol'].tolist()`

Demo Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[1,2,1],
                   'colB':[4,5,6]})
filter_value = 1

print "df"
print df
print type(df)

rows_to_keep = df['colA'] == filter_value
print "\ndf['colA'] == filter_value"
print rows_to_keep
print type(rows_to_keep)

result = df[rows_to_keep]['colB']
print "\ndf[rows_to_keep]['colB']"
print result
print type(result)

result = df[rows_to_keep][['colB']]
print "\ndf[rows_to_keep][['colB']]"
print result
print type(result)

result = df[rows_to_keep][['colB']].squeeze()
print "\ndf[rows_to_keep][['colB']].squeeze()"
print result
print type(result)

result = df.loc[rows_to_keep, 'colB']
print "\ndf.loc[rows_to_keep, 'colB']"
print result
print type(result)

result = df.loc[df['colA'] == filter_value, 'colB']
print "\ndf.loc[df['colA'] == filter_value, 'colB']"
print result
print type(result)

ID = df.loc[rows_to_keep, 'colB'].tolist()
print "\ndf.loc[rows_to_keep, 'colB'].tolist()"
print ID
print type(ID)

ID = df.loc[df['colA'] == filter_value, 'colB'].tolist()
print "\ndf.loc[df['colA'] == filter_value, 'colB'].tolist()"
print ID
print type(ID)
```

Result:

```
df
   colA  colB
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     1     6
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

df['colA'] == filter_value
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: colA, dtype: bool
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df[rows_to_keep]['colB']
0    4
2    6
Name: colB, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df[rows_to_keep][['colB']]
   colB
0     4
2     6
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

df[rows_to_keep][['colB']].squeeze()
0    4
2    6
Name: colB, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df.loc[rows_to_keep, 'colB']
0    4
2    6
Name: colB, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df.loc[df['colA'] == filter_value, 'colB']
0    4
2    6
Name: colB, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df.loc[rows_to_keep, 'colB'].tolist()
[4, 6]
<type 'list'>

df.loc[df['colA'] == filter_value, 'colB'].tolist()
[4, 6]
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use `pandas.Series.tolist`

e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
```

Run:

```
>>> df['a'].tolist()
```

You will get

```
>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

The above solution is good if all the data is of same dtype. Numpy arrays are homogeneous containers. When you do `df.values` the output is an `numpy array`. So if the data has `int` and `float` in it then output will either have `int` or `float` and the columns will loose their original dtype. 
Consider df

```
a  b 
0  1  4
1  2  5 
2  3  6 

a    float64
b    int64
```

So if you want to keep original dtype, you can do something like

```
row_list = df.to_csv(None, header=False, index=False).split('\n')
```

this will return each row as a string.

```
['1.0,4', '2.0,5', '3.0,6', '']
```

Then split each row to get list of list. Each element after splitting is a unicode. We need to convert it required datatype.

```
def f(row_str): 
  row_list = row_str.split(',')
  return [float(row_list[0]), int(row_list[1])]

df_list_of_list = map(f, row_list[:-1])

[[1.0, 4], [2.0, 5], [3.0, 6]]
```

Comment: Easier way is just to do `df['b'].values`.  If you select the column before using `.values` it will avoid a conversion and preserve the original dtype.  This is also much more efficient.

Comment: Which one is `the above solution`? All of the answers appear above this one. Thanks!