# creating array from csv Numpy python

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, numpy

I am trying to shape a array for use with scipy, sklearn etc.. I have a csv file I am importing using pandas like so -

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

which gives me this data -

```
>>print df  

Model | Trim | Cost
6     | 102  | 1200
8     | 105  | 1500
15    | 110  | 3000
```

I would like to shape it to an array like so

```
array = []
array.append(df)
>>print array

[[6,102,1200],[8,105,1500],[15,110,3000]...]
```

I have tried append, extend, shape, reshape and still cannot seem to get it right.. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748995/pandas-dataframe-to-list)

Comment: Do you want a Python `list` from it or a Numpy `array`?

Comment: ^ yeah you're looking for `df.values.tolist()`

Comment: Bam thanks! Seems so simple in heinz sight.. dont know how I didnt see that in my search efforts.. If you post as an answer I will accept, Thanks!

Comment: @m0nhawk should get accepted answer, I just followed their link