# How to incrementally print from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing, while-loop

Very new to programming - trying to get my code to take a list of order numbers from a spreadsheet then search them on an outside database. For now I'm just trying to get the "ONEA" column of my spreadsheet to incrementally print.

I think I'm miles off but the code below should at least explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Test1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

listONEA = df['ONEA']

# and what I'm trying to do is:

for i in range(10):
    print(listONEA[i])
    i =+ 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pandas Series (your `df['ONEA']`) has a method `.tolist`

```
listONEA = df['ONEA'].tolist()

for i in listONEA:
  print(i)
```

[Pandas DataFrame column to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748995/pandas-dataframe-column-to-list)