# Iterate over 4 pandas data frame columns and store them into 4 lists with one for loop instead of 4 for loops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am currently working on pandas structure in Python. I wrote a function that extracts data from Pandas data frame and stores it in lists. The code is working but I feel like there is a part that I could write in one for loop instead four for loops. I will give you an example below. The idea of this part of the code is to extract four columns from a pandas data frame into four lists. I did it with 4 separate for loops but I want to have one loop that does the thing.

```
col1,col1,col1,col1 = [],[],[],[]

for j in abc['col1']:
    col1.append(j)

for k in abc['col2']:
    col2.append(k)

for l in abc['col3']:
    col3.append(l) 

for n in abc['col4']:
    col4.append(n)
```

And my idea is to write a one for loop that does all the code. I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
col1,col1,col1,col1 = [],[],[],[]

for j,k,l,n in abc[['col1','col2','col3','col4']]
    col1.append(j)
    col2.append(k)
    col3.append(l) 
    col4.append(n)
```

Can you help me with this idea to wrap four for loops into the one? I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating a panda dataframe like a list usually works, but is very bad for performance. I'd consider using the iterrows() function instead.
This would work as in the following example:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4 = [],[],[],[]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    col1.append(row['col1'])
    col2.append(row['col2'])
    col3.append(row['col3'])
    col4.append(row['col4'])
```

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use loops at all; you can just convert each column into a list directly.

`list_1 = df["col"]to_list()`

Have a look at this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748995/pandas-dataframe-column-to-list).

Comment: Thank you this function to_list() also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to use `pandas.values` and then `numpy.ndarray.to_list()`:

```
col = ['col1','col2','col3']
data = []*len(col)
for i in range(len(col)):
   data[i] = df[col(i)].values.to_list()
```