# How to convert an element of dataframe to a varibale in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, sparql, dbpedia

I have a dataframe and I want to use one of its elements in my sparql query but it is not working with the following code. In deed, the value of pp is equal to ['http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eurobike'] while I need to have it in this way http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eurobike.
How can I convert this element of dataframe to a variable?

```
#testdf is a dataframe
pp=testdf.iloc[0:1, 100:101].values[0]

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    SELECT ?p ?o
    WHERE {  <""" + str(pp) + """> ?p ?o . 
    filter langMatches(lang(?o),"en")
    }
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(XML)
results = sparql.query().convert()
print(results.toxml())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert DataFrame to list and then modify list into string to use it in your query

```
pp=testdf.iloc[0:1, 100:101]
var_pp=pp.values.tolist()
```

and now you can use `var_pp[0]` in your query if it is string.
check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748995/pandas-dataframe-column-to-list) and [this article](https://datatofish.com/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-list/) for more info.