# How to extract a pandas dataframe column to a vector

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a very simple thing - to get a pandas dataframe column and use it as a vector.
I'm new to python. In R, using dplyr, I'd do:

```
my_data_frame %>% pull(my_favourite_column)
```

How to achieve this in Python?
I tried these:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PATH_TO_FILE, 'test.csv'))

my_col = as.vector(test['my_column'])
my_col = test[['my_column']]
my_col = test.my_column.to_string()
```

but no success.

Comment: duplicate of a duplicate >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748995/pandas-dataframe-column-to-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
my_col = test['my_column'].tolist()
```