# Sliced data into Arrays or List

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, slice

i have sliced data from my excel file below, and it giving me an output: now i want to convert this output into an array or a list how can i do it?

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\office work.xlsx',sheet_name=1)
df.iloc[0:1,10:17]
```

output:

```
P00 P01 P02 P03 P04 P05
0   5.630278    1.372496    0.055846    0.290576    -0.080946   2.540781
```

Comment: `df.to_numpy()` or `df.to_list()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame column to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748995/pandas-dataframe-column-to-list)

Comment: unfortunately it is giving me an error... 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_list'

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Why are you slicing on a range if you want a single index ? Try `df.iloc[0, 10:17].to_list()`, since slicing on a single index returns a `Series` instead of a dataframe, this should do the trick